# Same max-width for different items in complete html with css

Tags: html, css

is it possible to write a css-class in which the width is dynamicly the width of the most lengst item?

I would know how to do it in jquery (iterate through) but I need it in css / css3

Comment: Use scss for functions, css has the limitation where you have to re-write the length each time

Comment: @BhandariS Whatever is possible through scss should be possible through css too.

Comment: Can you please add example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: show me code then iam trying

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code to set the width dynamically

The width of all the rows will be set to the width of the longest row.

```css
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    width:50%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

ul::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

li {
    background: grey none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>row 1</li>
    <li>row 2</li>
    <li>This is the widest row 3</li>
    <li>row 4</li>
</ul>
```